# Vba open workbook, apply filters and close workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the following code to open an excel workbook, filter a column and close it again - saving changes.

Heres my code but for some reason it is not applying filters:

```
DisplayAlerts = False
OtherBook.Open
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="49"
OtherBook.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

My workbook looks like this:

Column A and Column B already have filters applied/switched on in their headers.

```
Column A     Column B   <----(Filters On)
49           Dog
48           Cat 
49           Dog
47           Cat
49           Dog
45           Dog
```

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Comment: Otherbook.Activate()? Application.Documents.Open(path as String) ?

Comment: does your code really work with that `OtherBook` statement?

Answer (score 0):

'Selection' works on the active workbook, it's perhaps a little vague, maybe try referencing your range more precisely. Change this line:

```
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="49"
```

To this:

```
Workbooks(OtherBook).ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="49"
```

Or this:

```
Workbooks(OtherBook).ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 2).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="49"
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. This doesnt seem to be working though. My header for column A with my filter begins at row 6, could this be the problem? I have changed Cells(1,1) to cells(6,1) - is this right?

Comment: what does field:=1 need to be?

Comment: `Field:=1` I think refers to the first column (field) in the range... and being that I referenced a single-cell range `Cells(1, 1)`, it's probably not affecting anything. The code works for me so I'm not sure where to go next... try the alternative suggestion I'm about to add in my answer... let me know if it's successful... here we're including both columns in the filter request.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Filtertest()
Dim rangetofilter As Range
Dim lastrow As Long

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  Workbooks("Calculator v1.2.xlsm").Worksheets("first").Range("dslist").ClearContents
  Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\username\Desktop\PPP\Test.xlsx"

  Set rangetofilter = Workbooks("Test.xlsx").Worksheets("copy4").Range("A1:F2586")
  rangetofilter.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="marketing"

  lastrow = Workbooks("Test.xlsx").Worksheets("copy4").Cells(Workbooks("Test.xlsx").Worksheets("copy4").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  Debug.Print lastrow

  Workbooks("Test.xlsx").Worksheets("copy4").Range("D2:D" & lastrow).Copy
  Workbooks("Calculator v1.2.xlsm").Worksheets("first").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

  Workbooks("Test.xlsx").Close False

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```